# Добавить флаги выбора у каждой позиции списка

Tags: django, django-admin

в админке имеется лист объектов, необходимо добавить напротив каждой позиции флаг для выбора (True/False), как на примере ниже
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или тут с вариантами дальнейших действий
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это реализовать стандартными средствами Django?

Comment: Тут в одном из обсуждений меня натокнули на мысль. Если я создам экшн для работы  с объектами (а сейчас экшнов нет) чекбоксы появятся автоматически?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить экшн, чекбоксы появятся автоматически